# How to fix the "alarms can be up to one month in the future" problem in elementary os loki?

Tags: release-loki

I've installed Elementary os Loki and when I resume it from suspend, the screen is completely black with this line:

```
tc_cmos 00:01: alarms can be up to one month in the future
```

I've searched for this without any solutions. I see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954315/black-screen-on-suspend) this same problem   and a related idea with the "solution"( [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367382) ), **but the problem hasn't been solved**

My machine is an Asus Dual-Core i5-7200U 2.5Hz. Nvidia Geforce 920 Mx and my OS is Elementary Os 0.4.1 Loki built on "Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"/Linux 4.10.0-40-generic GTK+3.18.9.

I'll appreciate your help and thank you.

Comment: Im having the same issue but unlike everyone else Im running into this on a server **SUPERMICRO 2U 6026T-URF 2X E5506 825TQ-R700LPB CSE-825 X8DTU-F** ▶ uname -a Linux BlackWater 4.14.15-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 23 21:49:25 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux ▶ dmesg | grep rtc -i [ 0.380465] RTC time: 15:37:54, date: 02/04/18 [ 0.822969] rtc_cmos 00:01: RTC can wake from S4 [ 0.823246] rtc_cmos 00:01: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0 [ 0.823282] rtc_cmos 00:01: alarms up to one month, y3k, 114 bytes nvram, hpet irqs [ 0.856923] rtc_cmos 00:01: setting system clock to 2018-02-04 15:37:54 UTC (1

Comment: Same problem in Ubuntu 18.04 after upgrading from 16.04 on Asus UX410U. Any solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not Elmentary OS but I had the same problem "alarms can be up to one month in the future" on Ubuntu Gnome 18.04 with Nvidia driver 396 and to solve this I use this Tuto : https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/969433 it works out of the box, if you have Nvidia Driver loaded.

Computer : Asus UX410UF i7-8550U - 16 Go RAM -  Nvidia GeForce MX130 
Ubuntu 18.04 - Gnome-shell 3.28.1